# Vim automatically inserts "* " add the start of every new line in css files

Tags: vimrc, neovim, insert-mode, filetype

If theres a "* " at the start of the previous line Vim automatically inserts a "* " at the start of the next new line. I want Vim to not insert anything.

examples:

```
1|* {margin: 0;}
```

When I press enter at the end of line 1 in insert mode it becomes:

```
1|* {margin: 0;}
2|*
```

It only does that in css files.

Comment: Does `:set fo-=r` help? Though it is weird that with `comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/` and with no `/*`, Vim would tread `*` as the middle comment marker. Might be worth filing a bug

Comment: After `:set fo-=r` it doesn't  insert `* ` anymore. `comments` is/was set to `s1:/*,mb:*,ex*/`.

Comment: I would consider reporting this on GitHub or the mailing list for more clarification: I wouldn't expect that value of comments to count `* ` as a comment leader when not preceded by `/*`, and as you noticed it is quite annoying.